# How can I calculate user session time from heart beat data in Presto SQL?

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

I'm currently recording when user's are active via a heart beat. It's stored in a table like so:

| User ID | Minute of Day |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 1 | 8 |
| 1 | 9 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |

- User ID 1 is active from 3 to 5 but then is inactive from 6 to 7 and then becomes active again from 8 to 9.
- User ID 1 was active for 3 minutes: (5-3 + 9-8) = 3
- User ID 2 was active for 2 minutes: 4-2 = 2

How can I calculate this using a SQL (Presto) query?

Output should be like so:

| User ID | Total Minutes |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the following which uses the lag function to determine active periods (`diff = 1`) before summing them

```sql
SELECT 
    USERID, 
    SUM(diff) as TotalMinutes
FROM (
    SELECT
       UserId,
       (MinuteofDay - LAG(MinuteofDay,1,MinuteofDay) OVER (PARTITION BY UserId ORDER BY MinuteofDay)) as diff
    FROM
        my_table
    ) t
WHERE 
    diff = 1
GROUP BY 
    UserID;
```

| userid | TotalMinutes |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 |

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ajy232GGXfysyPuxvT8exU/1)